# IntelliJ IDEA not detect spring configuration (with annotation)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm trying little spring project and encounter a problem if i use xml configuration file (web.xml and spring-servlet.xml) everything is fine. If i use java annotation the problem come up :(

I'm so confuse why intellij idea not showing my web views in my webapp folder.
[Not show jsp file (pressed Ctrl + space)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwbWP.png)
And cannot resolve any variable name in my controller class [Cannot resolve var name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaPYd.png)

```
### Controller CLASS ###    
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(ModelMap modelMap) {

        modelMap.addAttribute("message", "Hello, from java class");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

Configuration Class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.toskbilisim")
public class HomeConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource(){
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");

    return messageSource;
}
```

}

Comment: But does the Web.xml load the configuration?  And did u enable spring support?

Comment: yes web.xml load the config. I enable the spring support.